# ISO8601 time everywhere?

Tags: date, locale

I would like to have my dates and times shown in ISO8601. I have been unable to find a locale which supports that and which does not cause other programs (e.g. perl) to go berserk.

Which locale should I select?

(Ubuntu 17.04 is the most important platform, but I will prefer an answer that covers broader).

Comment: In what ways does Perl go berserk? For the most "standard" locale, use the `POSIX` or `C` locale (they are equivalent).

Comment: C does not give ISO8601 dates.

Comment: There is no such locale. What is the issue you're seeing with Perl?

Comment: Maybe http://terokarvinen.com/international_iso-8601_date_on_thunderbird.html or https://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-questions/2015-June/266181.html might help.

Comment: Raku (a.k.a. Perl6) has ISO8601 Date and DateTime classes built-in. Examples here: https://docs.raku.org/type/DateTime .